# ruby on rails - sorting model collection with complex logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, model

I have a collection of a model. I want to perform some complex sorting logic on this collection. The logic is not as simple as sorting based on a simple attribute. What the best way (performance and maintainability wise) to perform complex sorting logic on a collection of models. I am thinking along the lines of passing in a block to the sort method? But I am not sure...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a block using `sort_by`

```
@people.sort_by { |person| person.age }
```

`sort_by` uses the [Schwartzian transform](http://brandon.dimcheff.com/2009/11/18/rubys-sort-vs-sort-by.html) internally in sort_by, so if your logic is a little more complex than that, you can still create a scoring function and pass it to `sort_by`

```
@people.sort_by do |person|
  tier = if person.deceased?
    2
  elsif !person.important?
    1
  else
    0
  end
  [tier, person.age
end
```

Ask yourself if you can't make the sorting directly from the SQL query, this will be a lot faster (assuming the right query and indices)

```
@people = Person.all(:select => "*, (age + popularity) as coolness", :order => "coolness")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to read [this resource](http://www.scribd.com/doc/3965704/Ruby-By-Example-Chapter-6-Functionalism-with-Blocks-and-Procs), this chapter in particular:

```
#21 Using Procs for Filtering (matching_members.rb)
```

There are great filtering examples given using Procs and blocks.

PS: yes I'd use blocks even if your question is a bit vague.